# Codeigniter AJAX POST 66 records maximum

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

1. We have form with unlimited rows
2. Each row has 10 data attributes
3. All rows sends via AJAX POST to CodeIgniter script with AR as array of associative arrays
4. In script each row generate query
5. After all script runs insert_on_duplicate_update_batch 3 times and insert_batch 1 time

Content-lenght of ajax post request is 99299

ANY update&insert query produce only 66 rows !

Nginx + php-fpm

nginx.conf

```
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
```

php.ini

```
post_max_size = 8G
memory_limit = 512M
upload_max_filesize = 2G (dunno need that info but ok)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var aja = $.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: host,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {elems: arrayOfAssociativeArrays},
    dataType: 'html'
});
```

So if data to send like associative array need to increase value of php.**max_input_vars**
So, in **php.ini**

```
max_input_vars = 1000
```

to

```
max_input_vars = 5000000
;Dunno if 0 is unlimited
```